# Is there any way to add an object other than CString to a CComboBox in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, overriding, controls, ccombobox

I am trying to add an object that has a member variable `CString` to a `CCombobox`. I cannot just add the string because I am trying to interface with a tool that requires me to have another member variable other than just a string as a list item in the `CComboBox`. Below is what I am trying to do.

```
CComboBox::AddString(myOwnObject);
```

I only want the string of `myOwnObject` to display, but for the whole object to be in the listbox so that the other member variable can be reached by the other tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CComboBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx) wraps a native [Combo Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775792.aspx) control. It is a fairly basic implementation that meets the most common use case: Displaying strings for selection by the user.

If you need additional functionality, you can use a [CComboBoxEx Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zbff3f.aspx) instead. It exposes the full set of operations of the underlying [ComboBoxEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775740.aspx) control. In particular, the items can be configured to retrieve a string representation for items at runtime, based on arbitrary information.

The following is assuming, that your custom item data layout is as follows:

```
struct CustomItemData {
    CStringW m_Name;
    int m_SomeInteger;
};
```

The item data can be arbitrarily complex, and hold any information you wish to store. Populating a `CComboBoxEx` with items requires calling [CComboBoxEx::InsertItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8f2x66.aspx), passing an appropriately filled [COMBOBOXEXITEM structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775746.aspx):

```
// CustomItemData's lifetime must exceed that of the CComboBoxEx; don't use a
// stack-based (automatic) variable.
CustomItemData* pcid = new CustomItemData( myName, myInteger );

CCOMBOBOXEXITEM cbei = { 0 };
cbei.mask = CBEIF_TEXT | CBEIF_LPARAM;
cbei.iItem = currentIndex;  // The zero-based index of the item.
cbei.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;  // The control will request the information by using
                                    // the CBEN_GETDISPINFO notification codes.
cbei.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( pcid );  // Assign custom data to item.
myComboBox.InsertItem( &cbei );
```

At this point, the ComboBox control is populated with items, and will request the display information from the application. The [CBEN_GETDISPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775762.aspx) is sent to the control **parent**, so the notification handler must be placed into the parent's window (usually a dialog) implementation. The handler is connected to the notification message using the [ON_NOTIFY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/749htf6k.aspx) macro:

```
// Inside the parent's message map:
ON_NOTIFY( CBEN_GETDISPINFO, IDC_MY_COMBOBOX, GetCBDispString )

// Message handler inside the parent's class
void CMyDlg::GetCBDispString( NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult ) {
    NMCOMBOBOXEX* pncbe = reinterpret_cast<NMCOMBOBOXEX*>( pNMHDR );
    COMBOBOXEXITEM& cbei = pncbe->ceItem;
    if ( cbei.mask & CBEIF_TEXT ) {
        // Text is requested -> fill the appropriate buffer.
        const CustomItemData& cd = *reinterpret_cast<const CustomItemData*>( cbei.lParam );
        wcscpy( cbei.pszText, cd.m_Name );
        // Prevent future callbacks for this item. This is an optional optimization
        // and can be used, if the m_Name member doesn't change.
        cbei |= CBEIF_DI_SETITEM;
    }
    // Mark notification as handled
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

---

Occasionally it is desired to put the `CBEN_GETDISPINFO` callback inside the custom ComboBox implementation. MFC provides the necessary infrastructure to implement message reflection (see [TN062: Message Reflection for Windows Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd.aspx)). This allows a parent window to reflect notification messages back to the respective child control for handling. It can be useful at times, but is not required to implement a solution to this question.

---

If you do not need full control over constructing display strings at runtime, you can go with a simple `CComboBox` control, and attach additional information calling [CComboBox::SetItemData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ekb53ey.aspx) or [CComboBox::SetItemDataPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/690k2za3.aspx), as illustrated in [πάντα ῥεῖ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30534483/1889329).

Answer (score 1):

> *"I think what needs to be done is to override `CComboBox::AddString` "*

No, it's the other way round, you don't *override*`CComboBox::AddString`,
but implement your *other object types* to have an appropriate [conversion operator](http://Well,%20you%20could%20give%20your%20_other%20object%20types_%20a%20conversion%20[%60operator%20const%20CString&%20()%20const%20%7B%20return%20myCStringMember;%20%7D%60](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).):

```
operator const CString& () const { return myCStringMember; }
```

---

You probably want to use the [`CComboBox::SetItemData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ekb53ey.aspx) function additionally, to store the associated class instances' `this` pointer.

You can use `CComboBox::AddString()``s return value, to get the index needed to call

```
int SetItemData( 
    int nIndex, // <<< Fill in result of AddString
    DWORD_PTR dwItemData  
 );
```

Should look something like this (supposed you have the conversion operator implemented as mentioned above):

```
MyOwnObject myOwnObject("MyOwnObject1");

int newItemIndex = comboBox.AddString(myOwnObject);
if(newItemIndex > 0) {
    comboBox.SetItemData(newItemIndex,(DWORD_PTR)&myOwnObject)
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but wouldn't this just strip out the string and not add the entire object to the list?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between casting and using the dot operator here?

Comment: @Jameswr.11 I don't understand your questions. You probably should give a code sample in your post, to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I rewrote the question. Basically, is there any way to add an entire object to a ccombobox, but still only display just the string member variable from that object?

Comment: @Jameswr.11 Not so much improvement of your question, sorry.

Comment: this is what it boils down to: Is there any way to add an object other than a CString to a CComboBox?